# Two amplifiers in cascade

Tags: bandwidth

I want to do a simulation with two type amplifiers (PA107DP) in cascade to expand the bandwidth.
How can I do ? just I connect the output of first to the input of second (out-one I connect it to -IN of second amp) or there are modifications necessary to make at the input of second amp (like resistance ect )

[image]

Comment: And the reason for the cascade is "expanding the bandwidth"? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes that's what my boss asked me.
Because the bandwidth increases when the gain decreases so I will try to work with two amplifiers in cascade and with a gain which is divided on two amps and I will see what can give me by doing the simulation
My problem is how to cascade, I can't cascade them. (Is just a thread that I have to add that links the output of first through the input of second or are there other changes to be made at the schematic level by what I tried to just add a son but his was not walking)

Comment: That's a power amp, you don't cascade two of those. Drive it from an opamp, and split the gain between it and the PA. It seems to be intended to work in virtual ground inverting mode, as the +ve input is to GND, and the -ve input is described as 'summing junction'.

Comment: I didn't really understand what that meant, but even if it won't work it's just that I need the results of the simulation